# How to find a solution other than the vector $0$ of Linear System $AX=b$ with $b$ belonging to $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, lu-decomposition

Hello I am currently trying to find the solution of a spring system without condition on border, so naturally my vector $b \in 0_{M\{n,1\}}$, I am resolving this system with an LU algorithm but obviously the solution belong to $0_{M\{n,1\}}$ too.
Is there any algorithm solution other than $0$ ? Or do I have to modify my system to have $b $ not belonging to $0_{M\{n,1\}}$ ?

$A$ is a known square Matrix, $A \in M_{\{n,n\}}$, $X$ is the vector that I am looking for $X \in M_{\{n,1\}}$ and $b \in M_{\{n,1\}}$ with
b = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    0       
\end{pmatrix}

Thank You

Comment: What does "b belonging to 0" mean?    I suspect you want to diagonalize A and find its eigenvectors (when you say "a spring system" you mean a system of coupled harmonic oscillators? if that's the case, then definitely that's what you want to do), but I'll way untill you clarify it.

Comment: "b belonging to 0" mean $b \in 0_{M\{n,1\}}$, I do not want to diagonalize A, and that's right it is an coupled harmonic oscillators system (I started to write this system with the spring energy formula)

Comment: Then I do not understand the question, sorry. May I suggest you write with greater detail the meaning of all the objects?  What's  $0_{M \{ n,1\}}$, to start with? What are the dimensions of $M$ and $X$?

Comment: I have edited my Question

Comment: Apply gaussian elimination. If 0 is an eigenvalue of $A$, you will thus find a parametrization of the space of solutions, which is the Kernel of $A$. Otherwise 0 is the only solution. Either way, you'll find out by Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Thank you I will implement this solution